# Django rest-framework + polymorphic: serialize a list of URLs

Tags: json, django, rest, django-models, polymorphism

The relevant parts of my model:

```
class Item(PolymorphicModel):
    rating = models.DecimalField(default=0.0, max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    picture = models.URLField(max_length=200)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', related_name='items')
    # url_list

class Movie(Item):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    ...
```

I would like to have a list of urls in the Item class. This list should be serialized in the movie object serializer.

So far I tried to create a model to represent a URL this way:

```
class Url(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField(max_length=200)
    item = models.ForeignKey('Item', related_name='pictures')
```

But I get an empty list when a movie is serialized. My Serializers are:

```
class UrlSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = ScrollerPictureUrl
        fields = ('url',)


class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    urls = UrlSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        exclude = ('polymorphic_ctype', 'category')
```

I need to know how to serialize the url list for the Movie object so that it's not empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what I did finally:

```
class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    urls = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=True, slug_field='url')

    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        exclude = ('polymorphic_ctype', 'category')
```